# render data from controller before view

Tags: laravel

I have a project that needs to render data from the controller before pass to view on every page

Ex. `controller --data-->  {do something} --> view.blade`

I tried middleware, but it's not working, because it ??? before the controller.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this so we have a better context ? Maybe you want to do use a [`ViewComposer`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use the `render` method from a `Illuminate\View\View` object:

```php
class QuestionsController
{
    public function show(Question $question)
    {
        $content = view('questions.show', compact('question'))->render();

        // Do something with the $content string.
    }
}
```